# docker build failed : Not able to set the environment variables

Tags: c++, qt, docker, visual-c++, qt5

I am trying to build a QT application using docker.  I have visual studio 2015 build tools and QT 5.11.2 as base docker image. When I try to docker build QT application, I get this error.

> C:\Qt\5.11.2\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore/qglobal.h(45): fatal error
>   C1083: Cannot open include file: 'type_traits': No such file or
>   directory

When I checked for this file 'type_traits', inside docker it exists inside this path:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include

The docker build fails at this step:

```
RUN C:\\Qt\\Tools\\QtCreator\\bin\\jom.exe
```

This command `RUN ["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\vcvarsall.bat", "x86_amd64"]`  sets up the environment variables, How to verify that these still exist for the rest of the RUN commands in dockerfile?

Below is my docker file:

```
#My base docker image containing QT5.11.2 and Visual build tools 2015    
FROM qt 

COPY ["./", "C:/app"]

RUN $env:PATH ='C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin;' + $env:PATH;\
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', $env:PATH, [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine);

RUN $env:PATH ='C:\Qt\5.11.2\msvc2015_64\bin;' + $env:PATH;\
   [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', $env:PATH, [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine);

RUN $env:PATH ='C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe;' + $env:PATH;\
   [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', $env:PATH, [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine);

RUN $env:PATH ='C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include;' + $env:PATH;\
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', $env:PATH, [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine);

WORKDIR C:\\app
RUN ["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\vcvarsall.bat", "x86_amd64"]

RUN qmake app.pro -spec win32-msvc "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug"  
RUN C:\\Qt\\Tools\\QtCreator\\bin\\jom.exe qmake_all 
RUN C:\\Qt\\Tools\\QtCreator\\bin\\jom.exe    
RUN C:\\Qt\\Tools\\QtCreator\\bin\\jom.exe install
RUN mkdir dist\debug_build\app_dist  
RUN xcopy app_dist\dist_redist\*.* dist\debug_build\app_dist /E /Y >NUL

CMD cmd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to verify that these still exist for the rest of the RUN commands in dockerfile?

They won't.

In the environment that exists **here**

```
RUN ["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\vcvarsall.bat", "x86_amd64"]
```

executes a process that executes the batch file with argument `x86_amd64`, creating new environment
settings for any *child* processes - of which there are none - then exits. Then:

```
RUN qmake app.pro -spec win32-msvc "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug"
```

executes another process in the environment that existed **there**, which is still
the environment. And so on.

There's nothing specific to Docker, or Windows, about this behaviour. In any operating
system, a process cannot modify the environment of its parent, only the copy of
that environment that it inherits and passes to any child processes.

If you want all of the commands:

```
qmake app.pro -spec win32-msvc "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug"
C:\\Qt\\Tools\\QtCreator\\bin\\jom.exe qmake_all
C:\\Qt\\Tools\\QtCreator\\bin\\jom.exe
C:\\Qt\\Tools\\QtCreator\\bin\\jom.exe install
```

to start in an environment modified by `vcvarsall.bat x86_amd64`, then you
have run all of them in the same shell as that command, e.g.

```
RUN "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\vcvarsall.bat" x86_amd64 && ^
    qmake app.pro -spec win32-msvc "CONFIG+=debug" "CONFIG+=qml_debug"  && \
    C:\\Qt\\Tools\\QtCreator\\bin\\jom.exe qmake_all && \
    C:\\Qt\\Tools\\QtCreator\\bin\\jom.exe && \
    C:\\Qt\\Tools\\QtCreator\\bin\\jom.exe install
```

See also the dockerfile [`ENV` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env)
for a way of making global environment settings in a docker container.

Comment: Okay thank you so much. I tried to have run all of them in the same shell but I get dockerfile parse error. Unknown instruction qmake. Is it possible to run all of them in RUN exec format?

Comment: @user2301 Sorry I used Windows line-continuations (`^`). They should have been  Unix-style (`\\`) in a dockerfile. Updated answer. They're just for readability in SO anyway. It can all be on one line.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I am able to build successfully.